# React Redux dispatch on update causes recursion error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using React (14.2) and Redux. I have everything set up and working except when I dispatch an action on update, a recursion loop occurs.

```
componentWillMount() {
  const { wizardActions, valid, errors } = this.props
  wizardActions.setPropState({valid: valid, errors: errors})
}

componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
  const { wizardActions } = this.props
  console.log('NP', nextProps)
  //*** IF I UNCOMMENT THE FOLLWOING LINES THE APP GOES INTO AN INFINTIE 
  // RECURSION LOOP...
  /*if(this.props !== nextProps) {
    wizardActions.setPropState({valid: nextProps.valid, errors: nextProps.errors})
  }*/
}
```

How can I update the Redux state when the props for the current component change? I also tried this in `componentWillReceiveProps()` and it does the same thing.

TIA!

Comment: Use an `if` statement? Surely you only want to dispatch after updates with specific circumstances, such as `this.props !== nextProps`

Comment: Added the if statement but still same behaviour

Comment: Oh it can't be that *exact* if statement, because object references are always different.. that will always evaluate to true. You have to compare specific values inside props you want to be new.

Answer (score 2):

It is OK to dispatch actions in response to prop changes when those are caused by something external, e.g. React Router. But it seems like you want to dispatch actions in response to changes to props injected from Redux itself, which makes it cyclic. This isn’t really something you should be doing in Redux.

Where do `valid` and `errors` come from? If they are managed by Redux, there is no need to dispatch an action in `componentWillUpdate`—by the time you receive the new values, *they are already updated in the Redux state*. If they are managed by a parent component with local state, consider moving that state to Redux in the first place instead of duplicating it with two sources of truth (component and store).

Generally speaking there should be only one source of truth for any given state in your app. This source of truth can be a Redux store, a React component, or some external source, but you shouldn’t try to sync several sources of truth in lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

OK - to get this working without issue, I modified the `if` to be prop specifc as follows:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
  const { wizardActions } = this.props
  if(this.props.errors !== nextProps.errors) {
    wizardActions.setPropState({valid: nextProps.valid, errors: nextProps.errors})
  }
}
```

A few more things...

1. Thanks for all the replys and level of detail in some of them...
   it was @azium that lead me down the path to a solution that worked
2. ComponentDidUpdate is more intended for DOM manipulation and that is not what I am doing here
3. The props of concern (valid and errors) are injected by a Redux Form decorator. Redux Form does keep some stuff in Redux state, but not these - they are literally injected run-time props

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason that you can't use `componentDidUpdate` hook?
In [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillupdate), they note that don't call  `this.setState` in `componentWillUpdate` to avoid infinite loop. Redux's `dispatch` is not `this.setState`, but it will cause same effects.

Comment: componentDidUpdate is geared towards DOM manipulation that is not what is being done here